# How to return a stream of the first N Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to return a stream of the first N Fibonacci with N given as a parameter. So lets say if I pass 6 to my function I should get "0,1,1,2,3,5" or if I pass 7 I should get "0,1,1,2,3,5,8" and so on. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 def fibonacci(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
   if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n<= 2) return 1;

    fibTerm = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    return fibTerm;
 }
```

Comment: Can you please mark the top rated answer as correct? Thank you

Comment: I just did. Thanks Mario!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Fibonacci stream.

```
val fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1)(_+_)
```

Take `n` elements from it.

```
fib.take(n)
```

Here is how you can add it in your function:

```
def fibonacci(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
   lazy val fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1)(_+_)
   fib.take(n)
}
```

Note that the `lazy` is needed otherwise the compiler gets confused and gives:
"<> error: forward reference extends over definition of value fib"

Comment: Put those two lines in your `fibonacci` function.  That's all the code you need.  Those two lines and the end brace `}` and you're done.

Comment: Are you sure? it doesnt seem to be working. Did you test it?

Comment: That works for sure and it's amazing. I used to think that the Stream implementation they have in ScalaDoc was short. God.

Comment: Many thanks to @marios for the editing and clarification.  Apologies to @abpre.  I did test the code but I used `def fib` instead of `val fib`, which also fixes the "forward reference" problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answers from @dth and @jwvh are great. Just for completeness  here is another alternative:

```
def fibonacci(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
   def f(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = a #:: f(b, a + b); 
   f(0,1).take(n)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is actually how you should use streams. I've posted this solution as well at the almost identical question a bit earlier. I just wanted to point out that there is a direct way of computing Fibonacci numbers and got bored of giving the same answer to the same kind of question ;-)

Comment: Recursive stream definitions are so cool :). thanks for sharing your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

```
scala> Stream.iterate((0, 1)){case (a, b) => (b, a + b)}.map(_._1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res0.take(10).force
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this version even though its slower in case you really need all numbers ;-)

```
def fibonacci(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
   def fib(n:Int) =
      Math.floor(Math.pow(0.5*(1.0+Math.pow(5,0.5)),n)/Math.pow(5,0.5)+0.5).toInt
   Stream.range(0,n).map(fib)
}
```